# Activity Permission - Prevent User to View Other User Activity - CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, civicrm

I'm asking about activity permission in CiviCRM.
I've tried to search by default functionality to prevent user to view other user activity but i guess there is no feature to do this.

This is the case that I want. Example :
There are 5 users in CiviCRM : *Barnie, JohnDoe, Michelle, Danielle & Felix.*
User **JohnDoe** create new activity type "Phone Call" with contact user **Danielle** and assign to user **Barnie**.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kojgo.png)

What I want is : While user Felix login into system, while he find activities, that phone call activities above will not showed to him.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb6bZ.png)

Can you show me where is the code to execute query to prevent current user to view activity(s) that's not related to him/her?

Comment: why don't you ask this in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com -  lots more civi eyeballs over there

Comment: Thanks Pete. Will move there.

Comment: and paste the link back here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only inbuilt feature for achieving what you want is CiviCase - which restricts access to the Activities on the case to those users who are directly associated with the Case

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to change the original feature? Can you show me where is the query to get all activity that happened in "Find Activity" page

Comment: discuss in civicrm chat